# Use of ThreadDeath under Error

Tags: java, multithreading, error-handling

What is the purpose of ThreadDeath under Error which is  under Throwable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> An instance of **ThreadDeath** is
>   thrown in the victim thread when **the
>   stop method with zero arguments in
>   class Thread is called**.
>
> An application should catch instances
>   of this class only if it must clean up
>   after being terminated asynchronously.
>   If ThreadDeath is caught by a method,
>   it is important that it be rethrown so
>   that the thread actually dies.
>
> The top-level error handler does not
>   print out a message if ThreadDeath is
>   never caught.
>
> The class ThreadDeath is specifically
>   a subclass of Error rather than
>   Exception, even though it is a "normal
>   occurrence", because many applications
>   catch all occurrences of Exception and
>   then discard the exception.
>
> Since: JDK1.0

Source: [Java API](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html)
Example: [Link](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-976.html)